# How to avoid this strange date coercion

Tags: excel, vba

I have this formula in C4:

```
=TEXT(EOMONTH(NOW(),-1),"MMM-yy")
```

The date being displayed is `Dec-16` i.e. December 2016

When I then run this vba:

```
Sub makeDateValues()
  With Range("C4")
      .Value = .Value
  End With
End Sub
```

The date becomes 16/12/2017.

How do I safely amend the above so that the date stays December-2016 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can remove `TEXT()` from formula to:

```
=EOMONTH(NOW(),-1)
```

and just use cell formatting from main tools ribbon to diplay this number as you like.

[image: pic2]

[image: pic2]

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
Sub makeDateValues()

With Range("C4")
   .Value = Format(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, -1), "MMM-YYYY")
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

2 options:

**Option 1**

You can just leave it as a date and, inside your With block, add the line

```
.numberformat = "MMM-yy"
```

**Option 2**

Create the date within VBA in the first place

```
Range("C4") = Format(Now(), "MMM-yy")
```

Answer (score 0):

I amended the formula to the following:

```
=TEXT(EOMONTH(NOW(),-1),"MMMM-yyyy")
```

All ok now.